# JQuery datatable server-side columns collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I'm using Asp.Net MVC, all I need it's get collection of columns on server without creating a custom model binder.

If we look [Datatable docs](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) we will see `columns[i].name` parameter.

So I created **model:**

```
public class DtSentParameters
{
    public int Draw { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public IList<DtColumn> Columns { get; set; } //We are talking about this collection
}
```

Where **DtColumn**

```
public class DtColumn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetSales(DtSentParameters data)
{
    //here placed some logic, but it's not important for us.
    return Json(data);
}
```

**Datatable JS**

```
dataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        "url": url,
        "type": "POST"
    },
    processing: true,
    columns: [
        { data: "Date", name: "Date" },
        { data: "ClientAlias", name: "ClientAlias" }
    ],
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: true,
    jQueryUI: false
});
```

And everything works fine, I got my data and I can use paging. So i'm trying to add ordering, and here is a problem. my `Columns.Count` is equal 2 but name and data are empty.

I checked `Request.Form.AllKeys`

[image: Request.Form.AllKeys]

What we have, parameter `columns[i].name` looks like `columns[i][name]`. By the way `Request.Form["columns[1][name]"]` returns ClientAlias so it has right value but wrong name.

So maybe someone know why parameter name is different from official docs, and how can I change it.

I see only one desigions of my problem

- Custom model binder.

But all I want it's just use Datatables as [docs says](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters)

Any ideas how to get on server `columns[i].name` not `columns[i][name]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, with using an undocumented or good hidden feature. At least I didn't find it [HERE](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

All I done it's changed my dataTable init script

```
dataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set contentType,
      data: function(d) {
            return JSON.stringify(d);}      //stringify object by myself
       }
   });
```

And it's alive.